# Update not taking effect on SQLCe 3.5 with dataset and table adapters

Tags: c#, dataset, sql-server-ce

We used the VS2010 data connection design wizard to define a connection to a SQLCe database with just one table (database="UserMetrics" table="User"). Try as we might the update doesn't seem to hold, I've been through posts on SO and MSDN but can't see the glaring error...

```
        //initialize 
        UserMetricsDataSet umDataSet = new UserMetricsDataSet( );
        UserMetricsDataSetTableAdapters.UserTableAdapter umTableAdapter = new    UserMetricsDataSetTableAdapters.UserTableAdapter( );

        // check that test data is there and count is correct
        umTableAdapter.Fill( umDataSet.User );
        UserMetricsDataSet.UserRow umRow = (UserMetricsDataSet.UserRow)umds.User.Rows[0]; 
        int count = umDataSet.User.Rows.Count; //yep its there

        //lets add some rows
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            umDataSet.User.AddUserRow( "smith", (float)54, (float)3, 1);

        umds.User.AcceptChanges( );
        //umTableAdapter.Update(umDataSet.User); //tried this also ... no change...

        // there are now 101 rows !!
        int count = umDataSet.User.Rows.Count; //yep its there
        umRow = (UserMetricsDataSet.UserRow)umds.User.Rows[101];

        //lets double check
        umTableAdapter.Fill( umDataSet.User );
        int count = umds.UserMetris.Rows.Count; //huh!!! count==1 ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming `umDataSet` is the same thing as `umds`.

What about?

```
UserMetricsDataSet.UserRow umRow = umDataSet.User.NewRow();
umRow["Name"] = "smith";
// etc
umDataSet.User.ImportRow(umRow);
umDataSet.User.AcceptChanges();
```

Or what about reversing the order? The `TableAdapter.Update()` method sends updates back to the database based on the changes in the DataTable. If you accept the changes first, then the `RowState` is reset on each DataTable row, so there are no updates found to send back to the database.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171933%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

> In order to send the modified data to a database, you call the Update method of a TableAdapter. The adapter's Update method will update a single data table and execute the correct command (INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE) based on the RowState of each data row in the table.

```
try
{
    umTableAdapter.Update(umDataSet.User);
    umDataSet.User.AcceptChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // TableAdapter.Update() can throw exceptions
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the spelling. Your "ImportRow" suggestion had no effect though.

Comment: @Gio - How about the new example?

Comment: Sorry boss walked in & wanted an update. Thanks - that was it!