# How to upgrade SQLCE from 3.1 to 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

In the previous project, I've already developed an application with Ms Visual Studio 2005 and use SQLCE 3.1. Now, I have to add some feature there. Today I want to use SQLCE 2008(3.5). my sdf file still didnt work.
How do I upgrade it?

my error:

> {"The database file has been created by an earlier version of SQL
>   Server Compact. Please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrade() method."}

I already tried and get some source in [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/0e985984-d5ce-437d-8972-df2e82856ad7) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031391/update-not-taking-effect-on-sqlce-3-5-with-dataset-and-table-adapters), but it still doesn't work.

What should I do?
Must I downgrade my VS and DB or have another way to do it?

---

@joshua

of course i already try it, but the error message still like before i put it there. the output still detail:

> unhandeled exception has occured in your application. if you click
>   continue. the application will ignore this error and attempt to
>   continue". if you click quit, the application will close immidiately
>   the databe file has been created by an earlier version of SQL server
>   compact. please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrader() method it still
>   display.

what should i do now?

Answer (score 1):

I hate to ask it like this, but did you try calling the [SqlCeEngine.Upgrade()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896158%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method like the error message stated. That method is supposed to upgrade the SDF file from SQLCE 3.1 to SQLCE 3.5.

It should work like this:

```
SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine("Data Source=data.sdf");
engine.Upgrade();
```

Comment: of course i already try it, but the error message still like before i put it there. the output still detail:
"unhandeled exception has occured in your application. if you click continue. the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue". if you click quit, the application will close immidiately

the databe file has been created by an earlier version of SQL server compact. please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrader() method

it still display. what should i do now?